# How to download data using js with a browser?

Tags: javascript, cors

I want to write a script with javascript. Then start it with my browser on my local machine in order to download text files from another website and then process this data with js.

I tried this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("readyState: "+this.readyState+", status: "+this.status);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://website.com", true);
xhttp.send();
```

But i always get this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://website.com. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

I am using firefox. Is it not possible to do this? Can i not download data from other websites using js inside my browser?

Comment: Some websites block the option to use AJAX to get to their data, you can use CURL.

Comment: @NirTzezana - More that they don't *unblock* it. The block is by default.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, it is blocked by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i not download data from other websites using js inside my browser?

Only if they let you by supporting CORS and allowing your origin, or by providing a JSONP (rather than ajax) API.

However, since you're doing this locally, if you want to use JavaScript to do it you can do it with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) rather than in a browser. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies to browsers, specifically (it's for **your** protection, not the website's protection). It doesn't apply to non-browser applications like Node.js.

Or if you were only using JavaScript because you thought you had to, you can use any number of other tools (such as `curl` on *nix).

Comment: Ok thanks, i dident know the server blocked it, i thought its my browser, i wanted to use javascript with my browser, but if it doesnt work like this i will use something else.

Comment: @Alexanus - It's your browser that actually does the blocking. When you make a cross-origin request, unless the server includes specific HTTP headers with the response, the browser refuses to pass the response to the JavaScript code. So by default, cross-origin requests are blocked, but the server can allow the request to succeed by providing HTTP headers telling the browser it's okay to pass the response on to the JavaScript code. Fundamentally this is about not allowing website A to see info from website B if website B doesn't specifically allow access to that info from A.

Comment: Think of A as `malicious.example.com` and B as `yourbank.com`. :-) The issue is that if you have an active browsing session with your bank, going to `malicious.example.com` shouldn't leak information about your finances from `yourbank.com` to `malicious.example.com` (or worse, accidentally allow `malicious.example.com` to do a transfer out of your account...).